# Power Query. How can I dynamically transform a list of records to columns?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm returning some JSON data from an API.  There's an ID, a bunch of other fields (not included in this), and most importantly a List. The List contains a number of records (the same number and structure for each row)

I'm trying to map the records to columns rather than having to "Expand to New Rows".  Each record in the list contains 3 fields (ID, Value & Text).

This is the current structure:

[image]

I would like to transform the list of records to look something like this:

[image]

The number of records within the List can change. So today I have 2 records in a List for each ID, but tomorrow there could be 4 records.    So I need something dynamic that will add a new column into the table based on each record available in the list.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works.  Built in sample.

```
let Source =  Table.AddColumn(#table({"ID"}, {{"111"}, {"222"},{"333"}}), "Custom", each List.Repeat({[ID="Field", Value="BOB",Text="ASDSD"]},3)),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom.2", each Table.FromRecords([Custom])),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
Names= Table.ColumnNames ( Table.Combine ( #"Added Index"[Custom.2] ) ),
NewNames=List.Transform(Names, each "extracted"&_),
Expand= Table.ExpandTableColumn ( #"Added Index", "Custom.2", Names,NewNames ),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Expand,{"Custom"}),
Unpivot=Table.Unpivot(#"Removed Columns",NewNames,"attribute","value"),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Unpivot, {"Index"}, {{"data", each 
    Table.TransformColumns(
    Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index2", 1, 1, Int64.Type)
    ,{{"Index2", each Number.RoundUp(_/ List.Count(NewNames),0), type number}})
  , type table }}),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"data"}),
ColumnsToExpand = List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column(#"Removed Other Columns", "data"), each if _ is table then Table.ColumnNames(_) else {}))),
#"Expanded Part2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "data",ColumnsToExpand ,ColumnsToExpand ),
#"Merged Columns1" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Part2", {{"Index2", type text}}, "en-US"),{"Index2", "attribute"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Merged Columns1", List.Distinct(#"Merged Columns1"[Merged]), "Merged", "value")
in   #"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: thanks - appreciate it.  Let me give that a try!